# Problems with instalation of Zend-framework

Tags: apache2, php, zend

When I type this command:

```
apt-get install zend-framework
```

I am getting this error:

```
dpkg: error processing zend-framework (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-common
 php5-cli
 libapache2-mod-php5
 php5-curl
 php5-gd
 php5-intl
 php5-mysql
 php5-pspell
 php5-recode
 php5-snmp
 php5-sqlite
 php5-tidy
 php5-xmlrpc
 php5-xsl
 php-pear
 php5
 libzend-framework-php
 zend-framework-bin
 zend-framework
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have already install apache2, php5 and mysql on my Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

You could try another route:

Rather than installing Zend Framework system wide, you could use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and pull ZF as your project dependency. Usually it is much cleaner way to install ZF and similar packages.

Once you have composer up and running, all you need is this in your composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework1": "1.*"
    },
}
```

This article might help you going: http://adamcod.es/2013/05/10/composer-and-zend-framework-1.x.html